# cannot npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, karma-jasmine

I have found out an annoying problem about the captioned module.

When I install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor, it always ends in the following error:

```
>fsevents@0.2.1 install /Library/WebServer/Documents/node_modules/fsevents
>node-gyp rebuild
......
nam WARN karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-chrome-launcher but none was installed.
......
```

What is the cause of the problem? Is there another way to unit-test templateUrl other than using this package?

Thanks

Comment: Try running

    npm install karma-chrome-launcher

Comment: In fact I have already installed karma globally. version 0.13

Comment: Try running npm uninstall karma and then run npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor --save-dev

Comment: no luck
karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor@1.0.0 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay think I now it.

After you have removed Karma globally, try to install it again with:

```
npm install karma
```

Then also run a:

```
npm install karma --save-dev
```

Now try to install your ng-html2js-preprocessor by saying:

```
npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor --save-dev
```

If this doesn't work please copy the new exception and get back here.

Comment: It works! I really want to complain that why makes it such a difficult to install it.